# Open a .ppm file and write some data to it. AMD64 linux Assembly Nasm

Tags: linux, assembly, nasm, x86-64, amd-processor

I am writing a program in AMD64 linux Assembly code (assembler Nasm) that does a whole bunch of stuff. Basicly, my question right now is how can I open a file, and write some data to it.

My code I have seems like it should work.

Basically I want to open a .ppm image file and write the header to it. My professor gave me some pseudo code to to help and here is that code for just the part I am trying to accomplish.

```
fd = open("gradient.ppm", 577, 0o644)
if fd < 0: return 1 (error)

bufsize = writeHeader(buffer, 256, 256)
status = write(fd, buffer, bufsize)
if status < 0: return 2 (error)
```

Here is my code. My professor has some test program written in c++ that will run my code and test to see if it works correctly, so I am not running directly from this file. (BTW, the writeheader file has been confirmed to work)

```
global start
extern writeRGB
extern writeHeader

section .data
filename:       db "gradient.ppm",0

section .bss
buffer      resb 5000

section .text
            ; rdi,rsi,rdx
start:

            push r8
            push r9
            push r10
            push r11
            push r12
            push r13
            push r14
            push r15

            ; open file
            ; sys_open: rax=2, rdi=char filename, rsi=int flags, rdx=int mode   
            mov rax, 2                      ; 2 is system call number for sys_open
            mov rdi, filename               ; filname is in data section
            mov rsi, 577                    ; flag that is just given to me
            mov rdx, 0o644                  ; Octol number of the mode that is just given to me
            syscall                         ; execute the sys_open system call
            mov r9, rax                     ; r9 will hold file handle (fd)

            ; check for error
            ; compare 0 and data returned to rax from opening file.
            ; if data in rax < 0, store 1 in r11 and jump .error which will return the 1
            mov r11, 1
            cmp r9, 0
            jl .error

            ; call writeheader
            ; writeHeader(rdi = buffer, rsi = 256, rdx = 256)
            mov rdi, buffer
            mov rsi, 256
            mov rdx, 256
            call writeHeader
            mov r8, rax                     ; store the buffer size (bufsize) in r8

            ; status = write(fd, buffer, bufsize)
            ; sys_write: rax=1, rdi=fd, rsi=buffer, rdx=bufsize)
            mov rax, 1                      ; 1 is the system call number for sys_write
            mov rdi, r9                     ; the file handle (fd) is stored in r9
            mov rsi, buffer                 ; the buffer is in the .bss section
            mov rdx, r8                     ; r8 holds the buffer size (bufsize)
            syscall                         ; execute the sys_write system call
            mov r10, rax                    ; status will be stored in r10

            ; check for error
            ; compare 0 and data returned to rax from opening file.
            mov r11, 2
            cmp r9, 0
            jl .error


            pop r15
            pop r14
            pop r13
            pop r12
            pop r11
            pop r10
            pop r9
            pop r8

            mov rax, 0
            ret




.error:
            ; mov error code in r11 into rax to indicate error, and return it
            mov rax, r11                ; rll holds error code
            ret
```

If my code should work, then there is probably something wrong in which the way the test file is accessing it, if thats the case just let me know so that I can focus my resources on fixing that problem rather than fixing my code that already works.

Comment: are you sure it's `substitute user do` code, not pseudo-code?

Comment: I have never heard of "substitute user do" code before. I just looked it up and the term "Sudo" is short for that phrase. So yes, that is another way to say sudo code.

Comment: No. "sudo" is not what you think it is. You just don't know how to spell "pseudo" .

Comment: Ya, I think your right.

Answer (score 3):

```
cmp r9, 0
jb .error  ; <-- This will never happen!
```

When testing for a negative number don't use `jb`. That's reserved to work with unsigned numbers. Use `jl`.

```
cmp r9, 0
jl .error
```

Comment: I fixed that problem, but it still won't create the file. The more I look at my code, the more I am certain that it is correct, its just I  am running and linking everything wrong. However, I am really new to assembly and my code could be opening the file wrong. Is there any other problems you see?

Comment: If you jump to `.error`, you attempt to `ret` without popping all that stuff you pushed.

Comment: Is 577, The "flag that is just given to you" supposed to be expressed in decimal? It "looks like" a plausible flag in hex - `0x577` or `577h`. That's just a hunch.

Answer (score 0):

```
    ;open file  give it a name in section .data file: db "......", 0
    mov rsi, 577
    mov rdx, 0o644
    mov rdi, file
    mov rax, sys_open
    syscall
    mov r13, rax            ;save file descriptor
    cmp rax, 0              ;return error if negative
    jl .error
```

Comment: Can you explain what it was that he did wrong and what you fixed?

Answer (score 0):

Copy/paste related error in your code!

```
     ; status = write(fd, buffer, bufsize)
        ; sys_write: rax=1, rdi=fd, rsi=buffer, rdx=bufsize)
        mov rax, 1                      ; 1 is the system call number for sys_write
        mov rdi, r9                     ; the file handle (fd) is stored in r9
        mov rsi, buffer                 ; the buffer is in the .bss section
        mov rdx, r8                     ; r8 holds the buffer size (bufsize)
        syscall                         ; execute the sys_write system call
        mov r10, rax                    ; status will be stored in r10

        ; check for error
        ; compare 0 and data returned to rax from opening file.
        mov r11, 2
        cmp r9, 0
        jl .error
```

You have put the status in R10 but are comparing the value in R9.